# Can't Access 32 Bit in Protected Mode

Tags: assembly, x86, kernel, osdev, protected-mode

During the development of a small kernel, I stumbled across a strange problem when booting up application processors using the APIC.

As stated on [OSDev](https://wiki.osdev.org/Symmetric_Multiprocessing) and the Intel-Manual, the processor first enters Real-Mode, and my goal is to get it to operate in Protected-Mode. After setting up a small stack and enabling the "A20"-Line and far-jumping to my 32-bit code, i tried to clear `eax` using `xor eax, eax` for sanity purposes.

To my suprise, only the lower word of `eax` got cleared, but the high word remained unchanged.

[image: Running the kernel in QEMU]

Funnily, if I simply do an `xor ax, ax`, instead of `xor eax, eax`, the register is cleared entirely.

Below is my code for bootstrapping an application processor using the APIC:

```
; Extern reference to the GDTR
section .data
extern g_gdtr

; Serves as a temporary stack used for flushing the cpu-pipeline
SMP_BOOT_STACK_SIZE equ 64
smp_boot_stack:
    dq 0
    dq 0
    dq 0
    dq 0

section .text
global __smp_ap_rm_entry
align 0x1000
[bits 16]
; Real-Mode Entry point for other processor cores (AP's)
; after a INIT-SIPI-SIPI was issued
__smp_ap_rm_entry:
    cli
    xor ax, ax
    mov ds, ax
    mov ss, ax
    lea bp, [ds:smp_boot_stack + SMP_BOOT_STACK_SIZE - 1]
    mov sp, bp
    
    ; Enable A20 line
    sti
    in al, 0x92
    or al, 2
    out 0x92, al
    cli

    lgdt [ds:g_gdtr]

    ; Enable Protected Mode
    mov eax, cr0
    or eax, 0x1
    mov cr0, eax

    ; Far jump
    push 0x8
    push __smp_ap_pm_entry
    retf

align 4
[bits 32]
__smp_ap_pm_entry:
    mov ax, word 0x10
    ; Doing this two times is somehow necessary (wtf?)
    mov es, ax
    mov es, ax 

    mov ss, ax
    mov fs, ax
    mov gs, ax
    mov ds, ax

    xor eax, eax
    int 3 ; To check for changed values in qemu

    jmp $
```

Moreover, I have also tried to assign a 32-bit value into a register, e.g. `mov eax, 0xDEADBEEF`, but only the `BEEF` part remains.

Does anyone have any idea why this is not working?

Comment: Double check that your `bits 32` is effective and the machine code is correct. `xor ax, ax` working instead of `xor eax, eax` usually means your assembler emitted code for 16 bit.

Comment: If you're in 32-bit mode, why does the CS descriptor show up as ```CS64```?

Comment: @sj95126 I don't think I understand your answer correctly. Where did you encounter this?

Comment: In the QEMU output image you posted, the line starting with ```CS =0008```. A 32-bit code segment should be shown as ```CS32``` not ```CS64```. Are you sure your GDT is correct?

Comment: @sj95126 Thank very much you for the hint, this was indeed the problem all along!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @sj95126 hinted, it seemed like I had loaded the wrong GDT.
After creating and loading a GDT with 32-bit Segment-Descriptors, the problem was resolved.

If anyone is interested, below is the code for my new GDT used for switching from Real-Mode to Protected-Mode:

```c
struct SegmentDescriptor32_s
{
    u16 SegmentLimitLow;
    u16 BaseAddressLow;
    union
    {
        struct
        {
            u32 BaseAddressMiddle : 8;
            u32 Type : 4;
            u32 DescriptorType : 1;
            u32 DescriptorPrivilegeLevel : 2;
            u32 Present : 1;
            u32 SegmentLimitHigh : 4;
            u32 System : 1;
            u32 LongMode : 1;
            u32 DefaultBig : 1;
            u32 Granularity : 1;
            u32 BaseAddressHigh : 8;
        };
        u32 Flags;
    };
} __attribute__((packed));

__attribute__((aligned(0x1000)))
static struct SegmentDescriptor32_s smp_ap_gdt[] =
{
    { /* Null-Selector */
        .SegmentLimitLow = 0x0,
        .BaseAddressLow = 0x0,
        .Flags = 0x0
    },
    { /* Flat Code */
        .SegmentLimitLow = 0xFFFF,
        .BaseAddressLow = 0x0000,
        .Flags = 0x00CF9A00
    },
    { /* Flat Data */
        .SegmentLimitLow = 0xFFFF,
        .BaseAddressLow = 0x0000,
        .Flags = 0x008F9200,
    },
    { /* TSS */
        .SegmentLimitLow = 0x68,
        .BaseAddressLow = 0x0000,
        .Flags = 0x00CF8900
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
; Enable Protected Mode
mov eax, cr0
or eax, 0x1
mov cr0, eax

; Far jump
push 0x8
push __smp_ap_pm_entry
retf
```

When the architecture manual says a MOV CR0 that alters the PE bit must be immediately followed by a FAR JMP, they mean *the specific instruction* FAR JMP (opcode EA or FF, depending on how you want to express the operand), and they mean it must be *the very next instruction*.  If you don't do this the effects are unpredictable. I suspect your emulator doesn't actually flip the switch until it executes a FAR JMP, so you're still in 16-bit real mode and the machine instruction `31 c0` still means `xor ax,ax` rather than `xor eax, eax`.

FAR JMP takes an explicit, absolute segment:offset expression; you can't just write `jmp far __smp_ap_pm_entry`.  I don't know what exactly you will need to write.

(See section 9.9, "Mode Switching", of the [Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer's Manual Combined Volumes 3A, 3B, 3C, and 3D: System Programming Guide](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/download/intel-64-and-ia-32-architectures-sdm-combined-volumes-3a-3b-3c-and-3d-system-programming-guide.html).  If you haven't already read this manual, now would be an excellent time.)

Comment: The PE bit gets flipped immediately on the mov instruction. After that is complete you are in 16-bit protected mode. After the JMP (or RETF) you are in 32-bit protected mode(if the GDT has a 32-bit CS for that selector). The results of the instructions after flipping the bit with mov are defined and predictable. You are in 16-bit protected mode after the mov but without an explicit change in CS. It is not required to follow changing the PE bit by a FAR JMP or equivalent right away if the instructions after the `mov` are ones that are decoded the same way in real mode and 16-bit protected mode.

Comment: The issue with decoding is of course the instruction prefetch queue isn't aware that the PE bit has changed and the `mov` itself doesn't flush it. So the architecture manual suggests the following instruction be something (like a JMP) that flushes the instruction prefetch queue. It doesn't have to be a FAR JMP either. Any instruction that clears the IPFQ will suffice including but not limited to near and far JMPs and CALLs.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I'm literally quoting the architecture manual here! "_Immediately_ after [the MOV CR0], execute a FAR JMP or FAR CALL...Random failures may occur if _other instructions exist_ between the two" (emphasis mine) It does license lcall as well as ljmp but that's it.

Comment: You may note in the same architecture manual a code listing that they use something else than a far jmp.as I don't have access to the architecture manual on my phone but there is a code listing for boot up ROM example with a protected mode switch. The primary problem resolves down to the IPFQ